# Python NLTK Categorized Corpus Creation

Tags: python, nltk

I am currently having some dumb issues dealing with the inclusion of files in all subfolders when attempting to create my Corpus.

```
CorpusList = CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader('X:\\HardPath\\SF001\\SF001_009\\TextForAnalysis\\', r'.*/.txt', cat_file='CAT.txt', cat_delimiter=',')
```

My issue is that all of my text files are not in a single folder.  They are all in subfolder.  How can i include all text files in this directory and all subdirectories?  If I have all the files in the "TextForAnalysis" folder then everything works just file.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `cat_pattern` option:

```
CorpusList = CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader(
    'X:\\HardPath\\SF001\\SF001_009\\TextForAnalysis\\',
    r'.*/.txt',
    cat_file='CAT.txt',
    cat_delimiter=',',
    cat_pattern='(.+)/*')
```